# MySQL add column based on values in two other columns and a dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have `MyTable`:

```
ID               autoincrement primary key
Column1          varchar
Column2          varchar
Column3          varchar
Column4          varchar
OriginalCount    int
```

and a dictionary assigning weights of the following format:

```
dict1 = {'Column1Value1':0.3,'Column1Value2':1.2,'Column1Value3':0.9,...}
```

I wish to add a new column to the table, `Count` that is the result of the multiplication of `OriginalCount * dict1[Column1ValueN]`

Using python 2.7.10 on Windows 10, how should I go about this?

Comment: Are you using a new enough version of MySQL that has JSON?